# What is causing this vector to error?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to count the number of words in a text file from the user, write them to a vector, and then output a textfile with the number of words on the first line and the subsequent lines consist of the words in the vector, displayed in sorted order. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

//gets user input for file names to open/write to
string getUserInput (string inputORoutput) {
  cout << "Enter desired " << inputORoutput << " filename (include file extension). ";
  string userInput;
  getline(cin,userInput);
  return userInput;
}
//ensures that string word is an alphabetical word
string isAlpha (string& word) {
  string newWord;
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (isalpha(word[i])) {
      newWord += word[i];
    }
    else if (isspace(word[i])) {
      word[i] = word[i+1];
    }
    else {
      newWord = "";
    }
  }
  return newWord;
}
//removes empty elements of uniqueWords
void removeEmptyLines (vector<string>& uniqueWords) {
  for (int i = 0; i < uniqueWords.size(); i++) {
    if (uniqueWords [i] == "") {
      uniqueWords.erase(uniqueWords.begin() + i);
    }
  }
}
//calls isAlpha, calls removeEmptyLines, & sorts uniqueWords in alphabetical order
void sortUniqueWords (vector<string>& uniqueWords) {
  sort (uniqueWords.begin(), uniqueWords.end());
  for (int i = 0; i <= uniqueWords.size(); i++) { //remove this loop if digits are allowed
    uniqueWords[i] = isAlpha(uniqueWords[i]);
  }
  removeEmptyLines(uniqueWords); //remove this loop if digits are allowed
  if (uniqueWords.size() == 2) { //alpha.txt wont work without this
    uniqueWords [1] = "";
  }
}
//adds a new unique word to uniqueWords vector
void addUniqueWord (vector<string>& uniqueWords, string lineToAdd) {
  bool doesContain = false;
  int i = 0;
  while (i <= uniqueWords.size() && !doesContain) {
    if (lineToAdd == uniqueWords [i]) {
      doesContain = true;
    }
    else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  if (!doesContain) {
    uniqueWords.push_back(lineToAdd);
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  vector<string> uniqueWords(1); //for some reason the program produces error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  string fileName;
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(getUserInput("input"));
  string currentLine = "";
  while (getline(inFile, currentLine)) { //reads input and tests for failure
    addUniqueWord (uniqueWords, currentLine);
  }
  uniqueWords.erase(uniqueWords.begin() + 1);
  uniqueWords.erase(uniqueWords.begin());
  sortUniqueWords (uniqueWords);
  inFile.close();
  ofstream outFile;
  outFile.open(getUserInput("output"));
  for (int i = 0; i <= uniqueWords.size(); i++) {
    outFile << uniqueWords[i] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code through a debugger to see where it's crashing?

Comment: Try changing any use of `operator []` to `at(..)`. Basically, see if you're going out of bounds.

Comment: Try to change `uniqueWords.begin()` from `uniqueWords.erase(uniqueWords.begin() + i);` to a "number".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that rather than trying to fix this code, it would be a lot easier to start over, creating something simpler and more efficient.

It's not *entirely* clear (at least to me) what your goal is, but I'm going to assume it's to read an input file, find the unique words, and show the number of unique words followed by a sorted list of them. You apparently want to only treat contiguous strings of alphabetical characters as words. Assuming that's so, I'd do the job rather differently. First, I'd create a ctype facet that classified letters as alphabetical, and everything else as "spaces":

```
struct alpha_only: std::ctype<char> {
    alpha_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        // As far as we care, everything is white-space:
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        // except letters:
        std::fill(&rc['a'], &rc['z'], std::ctype_base::alpha);
        std::fill(&rc['A'], &rc['Z'], std::ctype_base::alpha);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

Then, instead of trying to filter so only unique words get inserted in the vector as they're read, I'd insert *all* the words in the vector, and then sort and make them unique afterwards:

```
int main() { 
    // For simplicity, we'll just read from standard input.   
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new alpha_only));

    // Initialize vector from file:
    std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile)),
                                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    // erase the non-unique words
    words.erase(std::unique(words.begin(), words.end()), words.end);

    // Show the number of unique words:
    std::cout << "Number of unique words: " << words.size();

    // show the words:
    for (auto const & s : words)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to ensure that only unique words are stored, that can be done more simply (though it'll probably be slower). If you're processing large files (especially with lots of duplicates), you might prefer an `std::unordered_set`, followed by copying to a vector and sorting.

```
int main() { 
    // For simplicity, we'll just read from standard input.   
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new alpha_only));

    // Initialize vector from file:
    std::set<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile)),
                                 std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    // Show the number of unique words:
    std::cout << "Number of unique words: " << words.size();

    // show the words:
    for (auto const & s : words)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the program is that you've put it all together without taking time to understand the consequences/side effects of any of the individual steps, and as a result, you aren't entirely clear on what-all the program does. As a result, those of us reading it to try and help you have no clue what you were actually intending to do at most steps. For instance, the first line of main

```
vector<string> uniqueWords(1); //for some reason the program produces error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

The error means you have a null pointer, it's nothing to do with this line. It would seem you're not even sure how to use the debugger.

All this line does is create a vector containing one empty string. Why do you want your vector to start out with an empty string? It only seems to come back to bite you later on when you start doing this

```
uniqueWords.erase(uniqueWords.begin() + 1);
uniqueWords.erase(uniqueWords.begin());
```

That there - that's pure, solid, bad-code gold. If you were working for someone, that code right there would be grounds for dismissal.

I actually see some promising practices in parts of your code, assuming those aren't copied from somewhere else, my advise is: STOP. Delete all of the code, and start again. Work iteratively: Take the time to understand how each step is working so that you can incorporate it correctly. Walk thru your code with the debugger and watch the flow not only of the code but of the data. Look up [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and understand how it actually works, and while you're there, look at other options like std::hash.